# please help the issue with inserting TTL to Comsos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, parquet, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

I'm a bit struggle with these insert TTL to cosmos db by azure data factory:

The requirement:
source: ADLS Gen2 parquet files (not csv, have to be parquet)
Target: COMSMOS DB
need to add all records from paquet files into Comsmos DB with addional name value pair like: "ttl":7776000
business wants every record in cosmos db for 90 days, there'S TTL setting on container level for 2 years, however, for the records from ADLS parquet, it had to be set in item level for 90 days only.

some restrictions here:

1. Data Flow can't be used because it's not supported self-hosted Integration Runtime, and using Azure IR hasn't security approved by my company
2. can't introduce other components like Synapse or SQL sever as staging sever
3. can't use databrick notebook.
4. ttl column is not in the parquet file, it has to be added during copy activity

so, I'm trying to use the additional columns as suggested by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy
here is my setting:
I add a parameter in the pipeline, it's set as an int data type.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciQDG.png)
add additional column in the source:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lb9B.png)
the mapping like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyKTR.png)

so ADF will through error: "Document's 'ttl' property must not be non-digital type if any.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDbManagement"

I tried all ways to transfer ttl to integer data type but in vain.
I'm feeling Azure changes the data type to string for all 'additional columns' even if you set it as int.

Please help any possible I can insert TTL as int into cosmos DB, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, even if you set it as int, additional column's type will be changed to String at source.

[image]

As an alternative, you can create a Cosmos DB trigger in Azure function and add 'TTL' there.

Comment: Thank you Steve. If the assumption is correct, not sure why micrsoft  changes all additonal columns as sttring.  also not sure any timeline Data Flow can be used in Self-Hosted IR.